# How to get distance between two points in Android?

Tags: android, point

I set the two pointers inside `ACTION_POINTER_DOWN`

```
point1.set(event.getX(0),event.getY(0));
point2.set(event.getX(1),event.getY(1));
```

How can I get the distance between this two points?
Is there any way to get it?

I want the distance to make some Scrolling effect. With the distance, I can use it like a scalefactor and resize my Layouts.

I hope someone can tell me how to do that!

Comment: You could use Pythagoras theory to calculate!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Its not just Android..**

We remember from trigonometry class that distance between two points can be calculated using Pythagorean Theorem as demonstrated [here](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/distform.htm)

But in code basically what you want is as follows:

```
double d = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(event.getX(1) - event.getX(0), 2) + Math.pow(event.getY(1) - event.getY(0), 2));
```

Where d is distance between two points

Comment: I get an error... sqrt (double) cannot applied to sqrt (double,double)

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the code, I was supposed to sum the two squares, but accidentally added a comma.

Comment: A small Operator makes the difference! Thank you for your solution!!

Answer (score 10):

```
Math.hypot(x1 - x2, y1 - y2)
```

should perform a bit faster.

[Math.hypot](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Math#hypot(double,%20double))

Comment: I think your answer would be way better if you added a short explanation on why this should be a bit faster.

Answer (score 2):

Finding distance between 2 points is not android specific:

```
    double x1 = event.getX(1);
    double y1 = event.getY(1);
    double x2 = event.getX(0);
    double y2 = event.getY(0);
    double x = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2) - Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2));
```